# AutoCompleteExtender is firing, webservice is returning results, but these are not being displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocompleteextender

I have been banging my head against the desk over this one.

I have added a AutoCompleteExtender to my webpage, and have implemented the webservice method for it to call.  So far, so good.

Using Fiddler, I have checked that, when debugging, the webservice method is being called and is returning the results I'd expect to see.. but nothing gets rendered to the screen, there is no drop down?

Can anyone here suggest what I might have done wrong, or offer a suggestion for something to try as I am currently stumped:

Declaration of the AutoCompleteExtender in the webpage:

`<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender runat="server" ID="lookupAgencyAppSettingName" 
   TargetControlID="txtAgencyAppSettingName" ServiceMethod="GetListOfSettings"

   ServicePath="~/Authenticated/AJAXMethods.asmx" MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
   CompletionInterval="500" EnableCaching="true" />`

For completeness, here is the Webservice Method:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
    public string[] GetListOfSettings(string prefixText, int count)
    {
        string[] suggestedSettings = new string[0];
        List<string> settingNames = new List<string>();
        List<AgencyApplicationClientSetting> settings = AgencyApplicationClientSetting.All().ToList<AgencyApplicationClientSetting>();
        foreach(AgencyApplicationClientSetting setting in settings)
        {
            if((setting.SettingName.ToLower().StartsWith(prefixText.ToLower())) && (!settingNames.Contains(setting.SettingName)))
            {
                settingNames.Add(setting.SettingName);
            }
        }
        if(settingNames.Count > 0)
        {
            suggestedSettings = settingNames.ToArray();
        }
        return suggestedSettings;
    }
```

Comment: Just to confirm I do have EnablePartialRendering="true" in my ScriptManager - as I know this is often a common cause of the drop down not rendering correctly.

Comment: Is there any javascript error?

Comment: No, no javascript errors are reported. It just seems to do nothing with the array of strings that the being returned to it by the webservice method..

Comment: There should be something outside of that code you might want to look because I took your code and simply returned an hard-coded array and it worked fine. You sure that your browser is not suppressing JS errors? Did you set breakpoints in your web service to see if data is returned in correct format or data itself doesn;t have have characters which might be causing this?

Comment: I have set breakpoints in the webservice method, and I have also viewed the request to and response from the webservice in Fiddler and it's definitely returning.
However that tip did pay off, as I decided to return a simple array of string (which returned ten values, as opposed to my genuine code which was only returning one), and because more values were being returned, I noticed that the results were displaying, albeit hidden behind the dialog in which the AutoCompleteExtender sits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, in the end this turned out (somewhat annoyingly) a z-index time.
I'm not sure what z-index a dialog that is displayed using the AjaxControlToolkit's ModalPopupExtender is given by default (the highest z-index I could see on the page was 10001).. but somewhere behind the scenes it was being given an attribute that meant that my popup suggestions (from the AutoCompleteExtender) always rendered behind the dialog (couldn't see this however until I returned enough results to get the suggestions apepar from beneath the dialog).
In the end I had to override the z-index of the panel used as a dialog by the ModalPopupExtender AND the CompletionListCssClass of the AutoCompleteExtender thus:

```
            .popUpDialog
        {
            z-index: 99 !important;
        }

        .autoComplete_listMain
        {
            z-index: 2147483647 !important;
            background: #ffffff;
            border: solid 2px #808080;
            color: #000000;
        }
```

Anyway, annoyingly simple in the end, but thought I'd share just in case anyone else runs into a similar problem!